# Normalization of Projective Scheme is Projective

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $X$ be a scheme (for sake of simplicity say proper $k$-scheme) which is ***projective***, therefore there exist a closed immersion $i_X: X \to \mathbb{P}^n_k$.

Let $f: N \to X$ be the normalization morphism of $X$.

Why and how to derive that $Y$ is then also projective?

We have to construct a closed immersion $i_N \to \mathbb{P}^m$?

One way might be a technical overkill: Thereis a criterion that a proper $k$-scheme $X$ is projective iff it containes an ample sheaf $L$. So since $f$ is finite we can pullback $L$ to $f^*L$ which stays ample, tada!

But I'm looking for a more intuitive /constructive argument in order to understand the geometry behind this fact. Is there a way to construct such a closed embedding $i_N \to \mathbb{P}^m$ explicitely using the local properties (so on ring level) of the normalization map. Are the numbers $n$ and $m$ related?

Comment: The mentioned approach is probably the easiest and quickest way to do it. Searching for a deeper understanding of normalization is good, but be warned: things can go strangely. Consider $\operatorname{Spec} k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]/(x_1,\cdots,x_n)^2$. This cannot be embedded in any projective space of dimension less than to $n$ due to considerations on the tangent space, but it's normalization is $\operatorname{Spec} k = \Bbb P^0$.

Comment: Alternatively, take a chain of $\Bbb P^1$s over $\Bbb F_2$ transversely intersecting at rational points. Normalization increases the count of rational points quite quickly, so now $m$ depends on how many irreducible components there are, as a fixed $\Bbb P^m$ may not have enough rational points to embed the normalization.

Comment: Take a singular rational plane curve of degree $d$, call it $C \subset \mathbb P^2$.  Let $C^\nu \cong \mathbb P^1$ be the normalization. The pullback of $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^2}(1)$ to $C^\nu$ is $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1}(d)$ which has additional sections, $d+1$ to be exact, so the natural induced map is the rational normal curve $C^\nu \to \mathbb P^d$. Potentially one could find a way to "canonically" (with respect to the starting singular plane model) project this to a lower dimensional projective space while keeping it nonsingular, but that seems difficult. So $m$ is probably arbitrary.